# Microsoft Teams web client: how does Teams knows if a device is allowed or not

Tags: windows, javascript, protocol

In my company I am able to use Ms Teams only inside windows but when I try from a Virtual machine (Hyper-V) running linux it says that this device is not allowed.
So how can the Teams Server knows that I am on the right device ? Is it based on IP ? Does it use some kind of fingerprint like the user-agent of the browser ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. My guess would be that it uses the UA string. That's what happens most of the time at least. I for one use an extension called "User Agent Switcher" with Firefox. I use it only on select websites, but sometimes it's the only way to convince stubborn sites that my browser is just as fine as those browsers it would like me to install (but which I avoid for one reason or another). What is your exact problem? At which point do you get stuck with your research into the topic?

Comment: `Is it based on IP ?`  ... how could it be?